# How to not get spammed by mouseover/mouseout events when mouse is moving between subelements?

Tags: javascript

Best explained with an example:

```js
var root = document.querySelector("#a");
var msg_stack = document.querySelector("#msg_stack");
var last_msg = document.querySelector("#dummy");

function pad(v) {
  v = "" + v;
  while (v.length < 3) v = "0" + v;
  return v;
}

function hover(v) {
  var msg = document.createElement("div");
  msg.innerText = pad(msg_stack.children.length) + ": " + v;
  
  last_msg = msg_stack.insertBefore(msg, last_msg);
}

root.addEventListener("mouseover", function() { hover(true); });
root.addEventListener("mouseout", function() { hover(false); });
```

```css
#a {
  position:absolute;
  left:10px;top:10px;width:200px;height:50px;
  background-color:red;
}

#b {
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;top:0px;width:50px;height:200px;
  background-color:red;
}

#b:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;top:0;height:50px;
  border-left:solid 1px blue;
}

#msg_stack {
  position:absolute;
  left:230px;top:10px;width:500px;height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"><div id="b"></div></div>
<div id="msg_stack"><div id="dummy"></div></div>
```

Notice that as you move your mouse over the blue border while still staying inside the red, it gets spammed with unnecessary mouseout/mouseover events.

In my case that is expensive, in my web page I have elements layered ontop of each other 5 deep so the spam is much worse. Every mouseover/mouseout triggers a bunch of other things and if that happens 10x in a single millisecond, it makes things stutter.

I don't want to disable events passed up the html hierarchy (as in #b triggering mouse events in #a), that is desirable as the things I'm monitoring on my page also have weird shapes.

Is there a way to not get spammed by mouseout/mouseover if the mouse didn't really leave the confines of the monitored element and its subelements?

Alternatively, is there a way to detect that another event(the subsequent mouseover) is coming down the pipe while processing the current(mouseout) event?

Currently I'm setting a variable each time the event is triggered and then a 1ms timeout loop checks that variable and then triggers the other actions that need to happen on mouseover/mouseut but I don't like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout`.

`mouseover` and `mouseout` events fire when any child element gains or loses the mouse. `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events only fire when the element that handles the event is first entered, or completely left.

[Here's some more info](https://javascript.info/mousemove-mouseover-mouseout-mouseenter-mouseleave) on the difference

```js
var root = document.querySelector("#a");
var msg_stack = document.querySelector("#msg_stack");
var last_msg = document.querySelector("#dummy");

function pad(v) {
  v = "" + v;
  while (v.length < 3) v = "0" + v;
  return v;
}

function hover(v) {
  var msg = document.createElement("div");
  msg.innerText = pad(msg_stack.children.length) + ": " + v;
  
  last_msg = msg_stack.insertBefore(msg, last_msg);
}

root.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() { hover(true); });
root.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() { hover(false); });
```

```css
#a {
  position:absolute;
  left:10px;top:10px;width:200px;height:50px;
  background-color:red;
}

#b {
  position:absolute;
  right:0px;top:0px;width:50px;height:200px;
  background-color:red;
}

#b:after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  left:0;top:0;height:50px;
  border-left:solid 1px blue;
}

#msg_stack {
  position:absolute;
  left:230px;top:10px;width:500px;height:200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="a"><div id="b"></div></div>
<div id="msg_stack"><div id="dummy"></div></div>
```